# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have created the following function that makes a call to a third party API to create an order and on the response iam calling model function that checks if a user with the user ID exits or not and some operation is done accordingly.

```
createOrder: async function (req, res, next) {
    
    let formData = req.body;

    razorPayInstance.instance.orders.create({
        amount: formData.amount * 100,
        currency: "INR", 
        payment_capture: 1       
    })
    .then(response => {
        let planSubscription = await PlanSubscription.findOne({ user_id:formData.user_id });
        if(planSubscription) {
            // do something
        } else {
         // do something
        }

        return res.status(200).json(res.fnSuccess(response));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    
}
```

**Iam getting the following error in node console :
**let planSubscription = await PlanSubscription.findOne({ user_id:formData.user_id });
^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function****

Can anybody please point out what  is wrong here

Comment: The solution is in the error. `response => { ... }` is a new function body that has not been marked as `async`, so you can't use `await` in it. On a side note, this is why it's generally a bad idea to mix the `Promise.then` pattern and the `async/await` pattern; it makes the code less intuitive and more difficult to follow and catch these simple mistakes. Stick to one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `await` some expression inside a function which is not `async`. Just use `async` function inside `then`.See more about [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) here

```
createOrder: async function (req, res, next) {
        
        let formData = req.body;
    
        razorPayInstance.instance.orders.create({
            amount: formData.amount * 100,
            currency: "INR", 
            payment_capture: 1       
        })
        .then(async(response) => { //change here
            let planSubscription = await PlanSubscription.findOne({ user_id:formData.user_id });
            if(planSubscription) {
                // do something
            } else {
             // do something
            }
    
            return res.status(200).json(res.fnSuccess(response));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
        
    }
```